# HLM Model failed to converge in R: degenerate Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

Tags: r, mixed-model, convergence

I have a data that looks like this:

| Subject | Type | Score | DV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | type1 | -3.1415 | 10 |
| 1 | type2 | -2.9784 | 10 |
| 2 | type1 | 0.1904 | 7 |
| 2 | type2 | 0.2104 | 7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

For each subject, there is two rows, containing the standardized and centered score for two different types, but the DV is the same for these two rows. The data have 261 subjects with no missing data.
I used lme4 package from r and ran a mixed model using the following codes:

```
model = lmer(DV~Type*Score+(1|Subject),data=Data, REML=TRUE)
```

I got the following error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$lower, rho$pp),  :
  convergence code -4 from nloptwrap
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

When I set REML as FALSE:

```
model = lmer(DV~Type*Score+(1|Subject),data=Data, REML=FALSE)
```

I got the following message:

```
Warning message:
In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$lower, rho$pp),  :
  convergence code -4 from nloptwrap
```

When I ran the following code:

```
model = lmer(DV~Type*Score+(1|Subject),data=Data, REML=FALSE,control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

I got this message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$lower, rho$pp),  :
  convergence code 3 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- a trust region step failed to reduce q
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0123452 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

I am not sure why the model failed to converge and I am wondering if there is anything I can do to help the model run.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try fitting a simpler model. Without more detail it is hard to suggest any more.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I am sorry I got back to you so late. I have asked around and it seems like it would be hard to estimate a random effect with only two entries so I guess I will change my analysis :).